# Xamarin: Positioning in AbsoluteLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I would like to place my ScrollView from the Point(0,94) to the bottom of the screen.

(0,94,1,1) with WidthProportional and HeightProportional does not work.
The bottom of the ScrollView is out of screen.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this

[image]

The code is

```
<ScrollView
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,0.6"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        </ScrollView>
```

Because you want it to stay at bottom and ocuppy 0.6 (1 - 0.94) of the screen

But if you only want to position it and you don't care about the size, you should use `PositionProportional` instead of the `SizeProportional`

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the quick answer.
I mean I would like to place my ScrollView from the Point(x=0,y=94) to the bottom of the screen.
And I want this work on every mobile device. (Sorry if my English is bad. I hope it is understandable.)

Comment: Then you might want to use `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"`